# How do I configure EKS (Amazon Kubernetes) to use a different docker image repository?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, repository, eks

You’d expect a wuestion this simple would have an amazon tutorial or documentation, but I can’t find any.

How do I configure an EKS cluster to connect to a different self hosted docker registry? I want to start running the open source version internally.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59846614/pull-image-from-private-docker-registry-in-aws-eks-autoscaler-worker-nodes THe above shows steps related to yours.

Comment: HA! Thanks, that helps a ton!

Answer (score 0):

So if like me you reached this question, you probably were not aware that there is new syntax for docker repos in image names. If your image looks like reponame:port/path/to/image then reponame:port is the repo server. It's not just a name anymore...